# JQuery datepicker defaulting to 1970-01-01 when changing a separate form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to resolve this issue.

I have a date field using the datepicker and a duration field with either 7 or 14 days. The date picker works fine and even though I am defaulting the value selected to the date picker, if you change the days dropdown to 14 from 7 you will see that the date defaults to 1970-01-01.

```
<?php
$datetoday = date('Y-m-d');
$dateselected = date('Y-m-d');
$dateformatted = date('d/m/Y');
$daysselected = '7';

if(isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['days'])){
  $dateselected=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date']));
  $dateformatted=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($_POST['date']));
  $daysselected = $_POST['days'];
}
?>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
</script>

<form name="CheckAvailability" method="POST">
Select Date: <input onchange='this.form.submit()' class="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="<?php echo $dateformatted ?>">
Days to Show: <select onchange='this.form.submit()' type="hidden" name="days">
<option value="7" id="days" name="days">7 days</option><option value="14">14 days</option></select>
<button onchange='this.form.submit()' type="submit" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datetoday)); ?>" id="date" name="date">Today</button>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>
</body>

<?php

echo 'Date selected: ' . $dateselected . ' for ' . $daysselected . ' days' . '<br /><br />';

?>
</body>
```

How can I make the datepicker remember the date that it already has?

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Kind regards,

Rob

Comment: think you maybe need to tell the datepicker that you want to use d/m/Y format (in the datepicker's parlance I think this would become "dd/mm/yy") Otherwise it assumes "mm/dd/yy". You can set this as a default option when initialising the datepicker. I wonder if this is why it doesn't understand the value you inject into the textbox. (Sometimes, it might understand the date but interpret it wrong, e.g. 04/05/2017 is ambiguous unless you specify a format by which to parse it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing what you are asking but you can get the current date selected before submitting:

```
var myDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
```

and pass this with the form and then after initializing the datepicker:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', myDate);
```

reload the selected date it had when the page loads again after submit.

Comment: the current value in the datepicker will already get submitted because it's linked to the "datepicker" textbox which has "name='date'" and therefore will get posted back. I think the issue is maybe the format of the date that is returned from the server.

Comment: Yes, I missed seeing the value being set with PHP. I believe you are correct. They need to set the date format option upon initialization: `$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I completely understand and by setting the format to dd/mm/yy you are telling the datepicker to expect that format and it should work - but, it doesn't? I've spent some time on this, looking for other examples and trying various things but now it seems worse. Load the page, select a date and it goes back in time. Switch from 14 to 7 and it goes back in time. In order to show this I have created the following which may help: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/54kj-ghc5

Comment: I see, this is definitely the right line. The problem is that I am using a variable called $dateformatted in the DatePicker input field to present the date in a European way. if I use $dateselected, the US way, then it's fine. I need to use the yy-mm-dd format behind the scenes but I want the value in the field to be dd-mm-yy, is there a way around that?

Comment: I've answered my own question, you can use an altfield so show one date and use the other, more information here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField

Comment: @RobWassell Sorry only seeing this now. So you have it all figured out?

Comment: Yep - thank you. As per the last two comments, getting the dd-mm-yy to be consistent and using the altfield explained in the datepicker information link.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good luck!